# Why cross_val_scores works well but cv.splits shows error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried `cross_val_score`. It didn't show error.

but if I tried using `cv.split` It shows error

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 5)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, max_depth = 10, random_state=100, n_jobs = -1)
for train, val in cv.split(X, y):
    clf.fit(X.iloc[train], y[train])
```

```
FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
  return self.loc[key]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-9c8fe6b057e9> in <module>
      1 for train, val in cv.split(X, y):
----> 2     clf.fit(X.iloc[train], y[train])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    248         # Validate or convert input data
    249         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
--> 250         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    251         if sample_weight is not None:
    252             sample_weight = check_array(sample_weight, ensure_2d=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 542                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    543 
    544     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     58     elif X.dtype == np.dtype('object') and not allow_nan:
     59         if _object_dtype_isnan(X).any():
---> 60             raise ValueError("Input contains NaN")
     61 
     62 

ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

I check the NaN by `np.sum(X.isnull())` but data doesn't have NaN

but It works well below!

```py
for train, val in cv.split(X.iloc[:200000, ], y[:200000]):
    clf.fit(X.iloc[train, ], y[train])
```

I change the index, but It shows same error before.

```py
for train, val in cv.split(X.iloc[:400000, ], y[:400000]):
    clf.fit(X.iloc[train, ], y[train])
```

```
FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
.
.
.
ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

I change the index one more time, It works well!

```py
for train, val in cv.split(X.iloc[200000:400000, ], y[200000:400000]):
    clf.fit(X.iloc[train, ], y[train])
```

What Could I do?

Comment: The traceback says the NaN is in `y`, but you check for missing values in `X`.

Comment: But I checked y[:200000] and y[200000:400000]. It is same as checking if y has NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** There is probably a NaN in `y` somewhere between rows 200 000 and 400 000, and likely not very close to 400k.

**Long answer:**
You should check `np.sum(y.isnull())` instead of `np.sum(X.isnull())`,
because the traceback says there are NaNs in `y`. There will be NaNs there.

The cross-validation checks shown do not guarantee that `y` is all fine,
because there seems to be misinterpretation of what the last one does: `cv.split()` returns indices to the arrays you provide to it. In both

- `cv.split(X.iloc[:200000, ], y[:200000])` and
- `cv.split(X.iloc[200000:400000, ], y[200000:400000])`

the arrays have the same number of rows, and thus return the same indices. When you do

```py
for train, val in cv.split(X.iloc[200000:400000, ], y[200000:400000]):
    clf.fit(X.iloc[train, ], y[train])
```

you actually access rows 0-200000 in `X`. To access rows 200000-400000 you could do

```py
for train, val in cv.split(X.iloc[200000:400000, ], y[200000:400000]):
    clf.fit(X.iloc[200000:400000, ][train, ], y[200000:400000][train])
```

I suspect, if you do so, the error will reappear. Btw, the `TimeSeriesSplit` does not use all data for training, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#time-series-split). Since you only show fitting the classifier, but no prediction, the error will not appear, when the NaN is very close to the end of the `y` vector. The last observations in time series are only used for testing, never for training.

Comment: @0Hong If this answers your questions, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. Thanks!